# How to fix the mongoDB/node.js issue "MongoTimeoutError: Server selection timed out after 30000 ms"

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Please help to fix the mongoDB/node.js

```
events.js:174
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^

MongoTimeoutError: Server selection timed out after 30000 ms
    at Timeout.setTimeout (E:\Digital\PROJECT\digital-api\node_modules\mongojs\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\sdam\topology.js:878:9)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:436:11)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:300:5)
    at listOnTimeout (timers.js:263:5)
    at Timer.processTimers (timers.js:223:10)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at E:\Digital\PROJECT\digital-api\node_modules\mongojs\lib\database.js:36:16
    at err (E:\Digital\PROJECT\digital-api\node_modules\mongojs\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations\execute_operation.js:76:14)
    at executeCallback (E:\Digital\PROJECT\digital-api\node_modules\mongojs\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations\execute_operation.js:67:25)
    at err (E:\Digital\PROJECT\digital-api\node_modules\mongojs\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations\connect.js:192:23)
    at connectCallback (E:\Digital\PROJECT\digital-api\node_modules\mongojs\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations\connect.js:343:5)
    at topology.connect.err (E:\Digital\PROJECT\digital-api\node_modules\mongojs\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations\connect.js:471:14)
    at selectServer (E:\Digital\PROJECT\digital-api\node_modules\mongojs\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\sdam\topology.js:258:11)
    at selectServers (E:\Digital\PROJECT\digital-api\node_modules\mongojs\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\sdam\topology.js:412:25)
    at Timeout.setTimeout (E:\Digital\PROJECT\digital-api\node_modules\mongojs\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\sdam\topology.js:877:7)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:436:11)
    [... lines matching original stack trace ...]
    at Timer.processTimers (timers.js:223:10)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your npm mongojs version is the issue. There is a bug in mongojs 3.3.3 npm.
you have installed mongojs3.3.3.

Need to follow below steps in terminal.

1. `rm -rf mongojs or npm uninstall mongojs`
2. `npm install mongojs@2.6.0`